# ExportToCSVFromList for Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to reuse ExportToCSVFromList that works in Yii1.1 with something similar for Yii2.

Is there any same as ExportToCSVFromList method, that works for Yi1.1 for Yii2 as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the extension, "kartik-v/yii2-export", that helped me alot and I solved my issue.

Hope that my answer help someone out there.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.